# Laravel With: Retuning subset of a relationship

Tags: laravel

I want to get a subset of related data using With method. I implement it as follow:

```
public function all($user_id){
   return Cart::where("user_id", $user_id)
   ->with(['products' => function($query){
    $query->select("products.*", "quantity");
 },'products.productsDetails' => function($query){
    $query->select("id", "price");
 }])->get(); 
}
```

but the second function return null all the time. How to get a subset of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you need to select the **foreign_key** `product_id`, so Laravel will collect `product_details` to each `product` by `product_id`:

```php
 ...
 },'products.productsDetails' => function($query){
    $query->select("id", "price", "product_id");
 }])->get(); 
}
```

Comment: you are right, is there away of not displaying the foreign key because its already displayed in the above relation

Comment: @Amir maybe u can use `protected $hidden = ['product_id'];` to hide the field for Relationship. And if you want to get this foreign_key for Model, you need to add makeVisiable. more [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)